# How to store URLs in Django right way?

Tags: django, url

I'm new in Django and sorry for such silly question. I wonder how to store URLs right way. I have in mine .html some hardcoded URLs to third party webserveces. And I know hardcode is a bad way. It's impossible to add those URLs to `urlpatterns` cause `url()` or `path()` requires to set certain views which I don't have. It will be great to concatinate URLs. Should I store these URLs variables in `settings.py` or somewhere else? Will be appriciated for any answers.

Comment: If this is just for one specific html template, then the view rendering this template should set these URLs. If this is in multiple templates, then I'd say settings.py is the right place, because it's a central place to go to if you need to change them later. You'll have to add a context_processor to your `TEMPLATES` setting to add these URLs to all of your templates contexts so you can refer to them like `{{ SOME_API_URL }}`.

Comment: @dirkgroten, don't quite understand. Where I can see some examples? I googled it, but it seems not such easy as I wish :)

Comment: [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) describes how to write your own context processor.

Comment: If you need them in templates, then I'd say the best place would be custom context processor (maybe even stored in database and populated in context processor, depending on how often they change). If you need those urls in views or anywhere else in code, then settings is probably the right place (or stored in database if they change often and you query them when needed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would probably be something like this.

1. Create custom context processor (`api_settings.py`)

   ```
   def my_api_urls(request):
       api_urls = {
           'api_1': 'https://api.example.test/',
           'api_2': 'https://api.test.example/'
       }
       return api_urls
   ```
2. Add it to context processors in settings.TEMPLATES

   ```
   TEMPLATES = [
       {
           'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
           'DIRS': [
               os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
           ],
           'APP_DIRS': True,
           'OPTIONS': {
               'context_processors': [
                   'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                   'django.template.context_processors.request',
                   'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                   'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                   # here you add path to your custom context processor 
                   # directory custom_context_processors
                   # filename api_settings
                   # function my_api_urls
                   'custom_context_processors.api_settings.my_api_urls'
               ],
               'debug': False
           },
       },
   ]
   ```
3. Use it in templates with `{{ api_1 }}` and `{{ api_2 }}`.

If they change often, then I'd store them in database and simply query them in views when needed.

Comment: I have my api_settings at ```base_dir/folder_1/folder_2/api_settings```. I've placed ```'folder_1.folder_2.api_settings.my_api_urls'``` to context processors but have ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder_1.folder_2.api_settings.my_api_urls'```

Comment: @PavelAntspovich, well, I can't tell what you mean by `base_dir`, but from django perspective the base directory is the directory where `manage.py` is.

Comment: @PavelAntspovich, is the file named `api_settings.py` and is the function in that file named `my_api_urls`?

Comment: Sorry, everything is workin. I don't know what is was but guess it was a typo